# Proper way to escape characters from RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, javascript

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, 
    page.GetType(),
    "KEY",
    "updateDockTitle('" + ClientID + "', '" + string.Format(format, ChartName, "No Data To Display") + "');".Replace("-", "\\-"),
    true);
```

`ChartName` has the ability to contain special characters (e.g. Someone's Chart). If allowed as is this causes an error the code hits the `'` when it was not expecting it.

What's the proper way to handle this scenario? Do I need to know all characters that could cause issues and replace them with escaped out versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this comprehensive solution handy:

```
private static readonly Regex scriptTagRegex = new Regex(
    "script", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

/// <summary>
///     Processes the provided string, creating a quoted JavaScript string literal.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str">The string to process</param>
/// <returns>A string containing a quoted JavaScript string literal</returns>
public static string JavaScriptStringLiteral(string str)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("\"");
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '\"':
                sb.Append("\\\"");
                break;
            case '\\':
                sb.Append("\\\\");
                break;
            case '\b':
                sb.Append("\\b");
                break;
            case '\f':
                sb.Append("\\f");
                break;
            case '\n':
                sb.Append("\\n");
                break;
            case '\r':
                sb.Append("\\r");
                break;
            case '\t':
                sb.Append("\\t");
                break;
            default:
                int i = (int)c;
                if (i < 32 || i > 127)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("\\u{0:X04}", i);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    sb.Append("\"");

    // If a Javascript tag contains "</script>", then it terminates a
    // script block.  Start by replacing each 's'/'S' with an escape
    // sequence so it doesn't trigger this.
    return scriptTagRegex.Replace(
        sb.ToString(),
        m => (m.Value[0] == 's' ? "\\u0073" : "\\u0053") + m.Value.Substring(1));
}
```

It should replace all invalid JS characters and also make sure there's no breakage if your script is inline (which it would be in your case).  Note that it already generates the quotes for the string literal, so keep that in mind if you decide to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The point is the escaping of the ' for your Javascript string. You need to escape that character with a \, making it `\'`

So your code becomes

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType()
       , "KEY", "updateDockTitle('" + ClientID + "', '" 
                                    + string.Format(format, ChartName.Replace("'", "\'")
                                               , "No Data To Display") 
                                    + "');".Replace("-", "\\-"), true);
```

*edit*

I think your code is false, the part that says

```
');".Replace("-", "\\-")
```

is useless. I would change your code to

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType()
       , "KEY", string.Format("updateDockTitle('{0}', '{1}');"
                             , ClientID 
                             , string.Format(format
                                             , ChartName.Replace("'", "\'").Replace("-", "\\-")
                                             , "No Data To Display")
                             )
       , true);
```

But then the question is, why would you need `.Replace("-", "\\-")` ?